# Allowing Users to Change Roles

Tags: wordpress

We have a site with three additional user roles which we added to the WP default roles. The "member" role is much like the "subscriber" role while the "backstage" and "artist" roles mirror the "contributor" role. The custom roles we are using are organizational, facilitate group emails, etc. These custom roles have the same capabilities as the default role they mirror.

I need to allow users to change roles when updating their profiles.

I can't seem to find in which table roles are stored. Any help in any of this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `wp_usermeta` table has a role field on user. To get a role from admin you can use:

```
$role = get_option('default_role');  //(fetch admin seted role) then insert like

$userdata = array('user_login' => $username,
                 'user_nicename' => $fname,
                 'user_email' => $email,
                 'display_name' => $fname,
                 'nickname' => $fname,
                 'first_name' => $fname,
                 'last_name' => $lname,
                 'description' => $aboutme,
                 'user_url' => $website,
                 'role' => $role
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```